# Would gargling with salt water every day increase blood sodium levels?

Tags: hematology, medicine, salt

Would gargling and rinsing with salt water every day for a few minutes increase your blood sodium levels? Considering the fact that sublingual medication is a very effective way for introducing substances straight into your bloodstream very quickly.

Below's a link to a study on Pubmed about this issue. Does anyone here have access? 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/3474267/

Comment: Do you think this question would be more suited for the medical science stack exchange?

Comment: Personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Biology.

Comment: @David it's a general question about sodium levels with regards to gargling salt water